# Good tactics for Anomaly Warzone Earth?

Tags: anomaly-warzone-earth

After a week of trying, I still can barely win 3 last missions at Casual difficulty. I tried every tactics I could think about, but I can't win these 3 mission at Normal and Hardcore (I once win a mission in Normal, by lucky, but now I can't do it again).

Can you please give me some advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I solved the last mission:

**Troop-setup:**

Crawler, followed by a shield generator, followed by a second crawler. At the beginning you should have enough money to fully upgrade the first crawler (allowing you to 1-shot the weakest towers) and the shield generator, plus I think upgrade the second crawler once. Naturally you should upgrade the second one as soon as you can.

You should not loose a single unit. While you can definitely recover from a loss, it's a good sign you are not active enough with your abilities. Also fully levelled units are very, very expensive.

**Alternative Troop-setup:**
On my first run I had the following troop-setup: Dragon - Shield - Crawler - Crawler - Shield - Supply (levelled to give decoys), with most of them levelled once or twice by the end. While this setup worked, I felt it to be much harder and much more micro-management intensive, since the convoy is much longer and therefore requires more smokescreens, decoys and repairs (the big laser by the processor required 3 decoys to cross without losses, while with my other setup, 1 smokescreen and 1 repair usually were enough since the shield was much stronger).

**Towers:**

- The basic towers should pose not much of a threat, especially in the first setup since you can one-shot them.
- An energizer should **never** get the chance to charge up your deployments. Luckily in the last level this is much easier than in the levels where it gets introduced. If you zoom out to the route-planning view, you can check for line of sights and plan your placements beforehand. Especially in the last mission I didn't bother and just called in airstrikes - one is enough and lets you do your thing freely.
- Hacker towers are annoying but no big deal. Stay out of the bubble and sprint in and out if you need to use an ability. Note that often the shot that deploys the bubble follows you. If you notice that fast enough you can run to a place where it won't get in the way. Remember, as long as you are in it and not your troops, no harm done.
- Behemoth/Stormray towers can be nasty. The former less so with my first setup, since the shields are much stronger, but Stormrays always can zap away all your shields in seconds, so decoys are needed. Try to place them behind the tower, so they waste time turning around. Also avoid placing them in range of towers you don't need to distract, they'll just help get the decoy removed faster. Be aware that if your troops are out of range of the towers but you aren't, the they might splash your troops by shooting you.

**Final boss:**
In the final bossfight, be careful not to bite off more than you can chew, let your troops circle somewhere where they'll be able to hit the boss while not being shot at by dozens of towers. One trick I used was to let my troops drive between the two "entry streets". You can hit two of the boss turrets while having few other towers shooting you.

Smoke screen works great against the turrets of the boss, while decoy is good against the lightning/splash damage towers, as long as you a careful not to place the decoy too close to your troops. Don't forget to drop aistrikes onto nasty towers aswell, they deal a lot of damage.

### General:

Also, don't be too afraid to let your commander get hit. He regenerates fast and if he looses all his health you only become unable to do anything for 3 seconds (though that can doom you if it happens at the wrong time). I abused this to let my troops circle somewhere safe, sprint in to airstrike a hacker tower, <strike>die a painful death</strike> fall asleep for 3 seconds and sprint out again.

And last but not least remember you can reorder your troops during battle. The front unit has no shields? Switch places with the third one and save a repair. Shield does not reset if you move a unit, as long as it does not switch the shield generator.

I hope this has helped, if not please explain more clearly what kills you.

Comment: Thanks, I've passed it ^^~ The second seems too hard for me, as the troop is too hard to manage them all, even my micro-management skill is not too bad.

Answer (score 7):

I've beaten every hardcore mission with a Crawler followed by 5 Supply Trucks or all Supply Trucks. That's Supply Trucks upgraded to three stars (airstrikes), by the way, and yes, it's a serious(ly cheesy) strategy.

Here are some preliminary observations before I go into the strategy itself:

1. Supply Trucks upgraded to 3 stars require 9 charges before they generate an airstrike.
2. When a tower dies, all Supply Trucks get 1 charge. With 5 trucks, that's 5 charges total, or 5/9 of an airstrike. Thus, you have to kill 2 towers to generate 10/9 airstrikes, or slightly more than 1 airstrike.
3. Blasters require 1 airstrike to kill; everything else requires 2 airstrikes.

Executing the strategy is fairly simple:

1. If you are playing "Squad Assault", "Squad Assault Reloaded", or a level where you don't start out with a lot of money, you will need to have one fully upgraded Crawler out front -- This is because power plant pylons take too many airstrikes to kill, and there are too many enemies to waste airstrikes on.

   - You'll have to upgrade the Crawler to three stars before purchasing Supply Trucks. Surviving until then is tricky but not impossible. Protect the crawler with a combination of smoke + decoy combos and repairs during combat. Note that the $1000 sunk into the Crawler isn't that much, if all you spend money on is upgrading it.
   - See other guides for squad management, not that you have much of a squad.
2. As you begin to add on Supply Trucks, upgrade them, and accumulate airstrikes, formulate a bombing strategy -- That is, before your convoy passes through, which targets are you going to obliterate/soften up ahead of time? There isn't much to the airstrike strategy other than following a policy. I've had success with the one described below.

   - Let's label Blasters and Scorchers as low value targets (LVTs), Behemoths and Storm Rays as medium value targest (MVTs), and Hackers and Energizers as high value targets (HVTs).
   - At the start of every level, destroy all HVTs, take all MVTs down to half health, and leave LVTs alone. Use the fully upgraded Crawler to "clean up" the remaining MVTs and LVTs. Exceptions apply below.
   - Sometimes you still need to destroy clumps of LVTs because they are too dense.
   - Plan your path so as to not approach Scorchers head-on. If that's not possible, just destroy them with airstrikes.
   - Be ready to repair after destroying Storm Rays. They can still do considerable damage, despite being taken down by one hit (assuming half-health).
   - Be ready to deploy decoys and repairs against half-health (assuming airstrikes softened them up) MVTs. Note that, depending on their orientation, half-health Behemoths can't even turn fast enough before they are destroyed by two Crawler missiles.
   - Take advantage of adjacent towers. Many times you will be able to bomb two, three, or even four towers simultaneously. Guesstimate and practice to get a good feel of what's possible.
   - If two MVTs or HVTs are adjacent to each other, just destroy them with airstrikes and spare yourself the hassle.
   - Energizers are sometimes your friend. On the last level, for example, there's one Energizer covering two adjacent Blasters, whose destruction yields an airstrike and repair ability. You can destroy both with one airstrike, repair to deliberately charge the Energizer, and repeat. The net result is 1 airstrike + 1 repair to yield... 1 airstrike + 1 repair + 10/9 supply-generated airstrikes. That's an effective gain of over 1 airstrike every time you do it! Thus, keeping Energizers around and deliberately feeding them with abilities can be quite profitable when you destroy clumps of towers covered by them.
   - Repair early, repair often. Why not? You'll have more repairs, smoke screens, and decoys than you know what to do with.

Disclaimer: I own the Android version, so YMMV.

Comment: I have to give this a try! The Crawler-Shield-Crawler combo is too imba is not challenging enough...

Answer (score 0):

I just sell almost dying units and purchase new ones.  I can do this over and over again without running out of money.